# Gulp is not generate js file from ts

Tags: node.js, import, typescript, gulp

here is my Gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var tsSources = [
    './typings/**/*.ts',
    'server/**/*.ts'
];

module.exports = function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(tsSources)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('server/'));
};
```

here is my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noLib": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "fonts",
        "images",
        "img",
        "libs",
        "navigation",
        "node_modules",
        "pagehtmls",
        "typings"
    ]
}
```

here  is  my ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/_all.d.ts" />
'use strict';
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
var config = require('../../config/environment'),
    auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


exports.getBooking = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    MongoClient.connect(config.mongoERP.uri, (err, db) => {
        if (err) { return res.send(err); }
        db.getCollection('customers').find({ email1: req.params.email }).toArray((err, customer) => {
            if (err) { return res.send(err); }
            return res.send(customer);
        });
    });
}
```

here is my tsd.json

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/_all.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "angularjs/angular.d.ts": {
      "commit": "2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571"
    },
    "angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts": {
      "commit": "c50b111ded0a3a18b87b5abffea3150d6aca94da"
    },
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571"
    },
    "lodash/lodash.d.ts": {
      "commit": "2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571"
    },
    "node/node.d.ts": {
      "commit": "2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571"
    },
    "socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts": {
      "commit": "2d4c4679bc2b509f27435a4f9da5e2de11258571"
    },
    "serve-static/serve-static.d.ts": {
      "commit": "b57c33fec0be3cba8f5e9cec642db873565923d0"
    },
    "mime/mime.d.ts": {
      "commit": "b57c33fec0be3cba8f5e9cec642db873565923d0"
    },
    "express/express.d.ts": {
      "commit": "470954c4f427e0805a2d633636a7c6aa7170def8"
    },
    "es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts": {
      "commit": "dade4414712ce84e3c63393f1aae407e9e7e6af7"
    },
    "mongoose/mongoose.d.ts": {
      "commit": "6766ed1d0faf02ede9e2edf2e66bbb2388c825ec"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using gulp cli version **3.9.0** and local **3.9.1**
its gives the error **error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected**
for the **import**
If i remove `'./typings/**/*.ts',` from gulp task and

```
path="../../server.d.ts" />
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
```

from my ts file its work fine but give diff error messages while compilation.
I have lot of ts file so i cant remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the the Problem..

**Just update your Gulp Typescript**.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not exclude all `typings` folder in your `tsconfig` as it contains definitions for the compiler, including the ones of `express`. Most likely you want to only exclude `typings\browser` for example.

Also I can recommend to use `tsProject.src()` instead of `gulp.src` so that structure of your projects is defined only in one place - `tsconfig`.

Hope this helps.